# Name of old book with two kids, treasure hunt, and elderly woman

Tags: identification-request

My dad loves reading old kids/young adult books to his grandchildren. For years he's been trying to figure out the name of a book that he read long ago, but he's been unable to. I'm hoping that someone here might be able to point me in the right direction!

Here's the description of the book, as my dad remembers it. Note that it's possible some of the details are incorrect.

Does anyone know what book this is?

> A family with a boy and a girl goes on vacation to a house in the country that's owned by an old woman. As the kids are exploring, they find a
> clue in a unique old chair. The clue is the start to a treasure hunt.
> At one point the treasure hunt leads them to a fountain. Eventually
> they find some jewelry (a necklace, I think). When talking to the old
> woman, they find out that her father used to create treasure hunts for
> her. They realize that the treasure hunt was designed for her, so they
> secretly put everything back and help the old lady do the whole
> treasure hunt herself.

Comment: Do you have any idea when your father read it? Even knowing the decade would help.

Comment: He read it in the late 80s, but I have a feeling the book may not have been written at that time. I know around the same time period he'd read some Elizabeth Enright (Gone-Away Lake, 1957) and Winter Cottage (Carol Ryrie Brink, 1968), so it would wouldn't surprise me if due to his taste the book in question was from a pre-80's era.